# Implementing Login Via Instagram 2020

Tags: android, facebook, instagram, instagram-api

Login via Instagram has been depricated.

Facebook suggested to use Login via Facebook for authentication.

Problem - Not all my target users have a Facebook account.
The App is to be made For Instagram users not Facebook users.

My app flow - Login Via Instagram (Input Instagram name and password -> HomeActivity), Get LoggedInUser Instagram info (Photos, Profile etc).

I just want to log the user via Instagram and get the logged in user *Instagram* Profile. NOT Facebook Profile.

I have read about the basic dispay API. but according to docs, It shouldn't be used for Authentication or the App would be instantly rejected.

**Question**

Is there a recent workaround/way to implement "Login Via Instagram" for authentication?

If Not, How do you suggest I do this knowing that my App is built for Instagram Users?

Comment: It is unclear what you actually require from this “login” here. If you just want to display the user some media from their IG account - then that’s what the IG Basic Display API is for, so just use it as described then.

Comment: On the App, Theres a profile section for displaying current logged in user Instagram media. Also, that same logged in user can search for ANY Instagram username and view their media also from the App.

Comment: So you are not using this “login” for _anything_ else? You don’t use it to control what the user is allowed to do in your app, you are not using it to identify them for _any_ other purpose than just displaying their IG stuff? Then I’d say, the IG Basic Display API is _exactly_ what you want.

Comment: How can I then keep the user LOGGED IN to the app. Without having to enter details each time??

Comment: You could get a long-lived token, and store it somewhere – then you’d be good for 60 days.

Comment: From the official doc, here us what they wrote - "*Note that Basic Display is not an authentication tool. Data returned by the API cannot be used to authenticate your app users or log them into your apIf your app uses API data to authenticate users, it will be rejected during App Review. If your app uses API data to authenticate users, it will be rejected during App Review.*"

Comment: If your app needs a login functionality, then you will have to implement it yourself. (Or use a different authentication provider, like Facebook.)